# Kaa Library for ESP8266 with Arduino IDE.

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, kaa, arduino-esp8266

I am developing an IoT solution using ESP8266 (ESP12E) and programming using Arduino IDE. I came across Kaa lately and was exploring if it can be used to power our servers. As I understand, we can develop applications on top of Kaa while Kaa handles all the communication between the endpoint (our embedded device) and the server.

I want to know if we can integrate the Kaa C SDK along with the Arduino code we have written for our application. Is it the case that Kaa provides header files/libraries that we can compile along with Arduino code or is it a firmware that we will have to burn directly to the chip?

I am just starting to experiment with Kaa and it would be great if there is someone who have tried implementing this solution can help out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's not arduino, it's hardcore C using the esp SDK: http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/ you might be able to convert your some of your arduino code, but libraries won't be available.

Comment: What are possibilities of porting it to an Arduino environment? The chip that I am using (ESP-12E) seems to have enough resources to run Kaa endpoint SDK along with Arduino code. Is there any way to cross-compile the Kaa C SDK so that it runs with the chip?

Comment: there very well may be cross compilation options, but that's beyond my paygrade. i would consider adding $2 onto the build cost and running 2 ESPs talking over serial or i2c.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Kaa C SDK is not integrated with Arduino IDE.

You can use Kaa to handle communication between the endpoint and the server, however, you need to implement the platform layer.
The Kaa C SDK provides a reference implementation of the platform layer for ESP8266: https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/release-0.10/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl/esp8266. You can use it as a starting point.